# 'UserCreationForm' object has no attribute 'get_username' django 1.8

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-1.8

So I'm a newbie to django, know python enough not to call myself a beginner but I'm by no means a pro. I'm just trying to get user authentication working on a small django app. I'm using the default authentication system https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/ and the built in forms, the login, logout, etc have their own views but the UserCreationForm doesn't have it's own view, so I figured I had to make my own. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

this is my views.py

```
  1 from django.shortcuts import render
  2 from django.http import HttpResponse
  3 from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
  4 from django.contrib.auth import login
  5
  6 def home(request):
  7         return HttpResponse("This is a barebones homepage")
  8
  9 def register(request):
 10         registered = False
 11
 12         if request.method == 'POST':
 13                 user_form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
 14
 15                 if user_form.is_valid():
 16                         user = user_form.save()
 17                         username = user_form.get_username()
 18                         password = user_form.clean_password2()
 19                         login(request,user)
 20                 else:
 21                         print user_form.errors
 22         else:
 23                 user_form = UserCreationForm()
 24
 25         return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'registered': registered}    )
~
```

this is my register.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
        <head>
                <title>Jet!</title>
        </head>

        <body>
                {% if registered %}
                        Jet! says Thank you for registering!
                        <a href='/'>Return to the homepage.</a><br />
                {% else %}
                <form method="post" action="/register/">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ user_form.as_p }}
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
                </form>
                {% endif %}
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the line `username = user_form.get_username()` is giving an error because, as the message says, the form does not have a `get_username` method. You can access the username with user_form.cleaned_data['username']

Secondly, the line `password = user_form.clean` would give an error, because the form has no attribute `clean`. If you needed it, you could get the value from the `password1` field with `user_form.cleaned_data['password1']`.

Before you `login` the user, you must authenticate them, otherwise you will get an error about the user having no attribute `backend`.

Putting it together, you have:

```
if user_form.is_valid():
    user_form.save()
    username = user_form.cleaned_data['username']
    password = user_form.cleaned_data['password1']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    login(request, user)
```

You'll have to import the `authenticate` method by changing your import to:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
```

Note that you haven't set `registered=True` anywhere in your code. Usually, it is good practice to redirect after the form has been successfully submitted, to prevent duplicate submissions.

Comment: So I changed views.py according to what you said, but now I get the error 
"'User' object has no attribute 'backend'"  What does that mean?

Comment: OK, I think you'll need to call `authenticate` before `login`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much. so just to recap, the mistake I made was that for forms I should use form.cleaned_data['attribute'] to get the responses in the form?

Comment: Yes, in the view you access the cleaned data with `form.cleaned_data['field_name']`. The other part missing from your code was calling `authenticate()`.

Answer (score 0):

change user_form.get_username() to request.user.username

```
username = user_form.get_username() = request.user.username
```

Comment: The user isn't logged in yet, so `request.user` is an anonymous user and doesn't have a username.